# preg_match with multiple find

Tags: php, preg-match

i have this code

```
$a='-t40-';
preg_match('/^-t(.*?)-$/', $a,$match);
var_dump($match);
```

Result:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "-t40-" } 
           [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "40" } }
```

if i add some text after last "-" code will not be valid.
if $a='-t40-some text'; i need a result similar with:

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "-t40-" } 
           [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "40" } 
           [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "some text" }}
```

How to edit pattern to find "some text"?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you want and if it will work, but try removing the `/^` and `$/` at the beginning and end of your regex.

Comment: i need to extract the code between "-t" and "-" and text after last "-" if is set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$a='-t40-some text';
preg_match('/^-t(.*?)-(.*?)$/', $a,$match);
var_dump($match);
```

**Output:**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "-t40-some text"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "40"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "some text"
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
^           : beginning of line
  -t        : literally "-t"
  (.*?)     : group 1, 0 or more any charater but newline, not greedy
  -         : literally "-"
  (.*?)     : group 2, 0 or more any charater but newline, not greedy
$           : end of line
```

Comment: Thank you, it's what i looking for!